# AWS CLI install with wrong arguments

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I was trying to install the awscli tools on a CentOS 7 instance, and I gave the installation script a bad installation directory. Now it appears that my Python setup on the host is broken.

This is the command I ran and the subsequent output:

```
[root@localhost awscli-bundle]# ./install -i /usr/bin
Running cmd: /bin/python virtualenv.py --python /bin/python /usr/bin
Running cmd: /usr/bin/bin/pip install --no-index --find-links file:///home/rhaskins/awscli-bundle/packages awscli-1.11.30.tar.gz
You can now run: /usr/bin/bin/aws --version
```

And now when running yum (for instance) I get:

```
[root@localhost awscli-bundle]# yum
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   No module named yum

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.7.5 (default, Nov  6 2016, 00:28:07)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

How do I undo this?

Comment: Ideally you're familiar with the pets vs. cattle metaphor and can simply discard this instance and start a new one from scratch. Also, it's not the best practice to be logged in as root.

Answer (score -1):

@jarmod, I am aware of the ease to which you can create new AWS instances and I was attempting to learn if there was an easy way to undo what I had done. In the end, I ended up building a new instance and installing the AWS CLI using the direct `pip install` method rather than the bundled installer that comes with the AWS CLI download package.